# Error when attempting to send SepoliaETH between two accounts in remix via smart contract with specific conditions: Cause of error -->undefined gas

Tags: solidity, remix, blockchain, gas-price, sepolia

I would like to use my smart contract to map a payment transaction from SepoliaETH from one Metamask account to another Metamask account. The conditions of a transaction limit and a recall function of the transferred amount are implemented. Although it is possible to transfer SepoliaETH from the sender account to the smart contract, I am unable to transfer this credit from the smart contract to the second account. The recurring error message indicates an undefined gas volume, which is also displayed in lines 9, 10, 23 and 32 of the code in Remix. Unfortunately, I do not have a solution for this problem. My only goal is for the second account to receive an amount to SepoliaETH and the conditions pass in the process. Maybe someone can help me, I would be very grateful for any help! Below is the code

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity 0.8.4;

contract SepoliaTransfer {
    address private admin;
    mapping(address => bool) private confirmations;
    uint256 private transferLimit; // Überweisungslimit in Wei
    receive() external payable {}
    fallback() external payable {}

    constructor() {
        admin = msg.sender;
        transferLimit = 500000000000000000; // 0.5 SapoliaETH in Wei als Limit
    }

    modifier onlyAdmin() {
        require(msg.sender == admin, "Only admin can call this function");
        _;
    }

    // Funktion zum Übertragen von Ether
    function transfer(address payable recipient, uint256 amount) external onlyAdmin {
        require(!confirmations[recipient], "Recipient already confirmed");
        require(amount <= transferLimit, "Exceeds transfer limit");

        // Markiere den Empfänger als bestätigt
        confirmations[recipient] = true;
    }

    // Funktion zum Rückruf von Ether bei Betrugsverdacht 
    function recall(uint256 amount) external onlyAdmin {
        require(confirmations[msg.sender], "Sender must confirm the transaction first");

        // Direkter Transfer von Ether vom Smart Contract zum Admin nach Recall
        payable(admin).transfer(amount);
    }    

    // Funktion zur Änderung des Überweisungs-Limits durch den Admin
    function setTransferLimit(uint256 newLimit) external onlyAdmin {
        transferLimit = newLimit;
    }

    // Funktion zum Abrufen des aktuellen Überweisungs-Limits
    function getTransferLimit() external view returns (uint256) {
        return transferLimit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you've provided is a smart contract written in Solidity for the Ethereum blockchain. The error you're encountering related to "undefined gas" could be due to several reasons, often related to the Ethereum transaction process itself rather than the contract's logic. However, your contract does not seem to have a direct issue causing "undefined gas" errors, but I'll highlight a few points to check and improve:

Gas Limit and Gas Price: When you send a transaction on the Ethereum network (including test networks like Sepolia), you need to specify a gas limit and a gas price. If these are not correctly set in your transaction, it can lead to errors. Ensure that your development environment (like Remix) is correctly configured with an appropriate gas limit and gas price.

Transfer of Ether: Your transfer function marks a recipient as confirmed but does not actually transfer any Ether. If your intention is to transfer Ether with this function, you should include a statement like recipient.transfer(amount);. Otherwise, this function doesn't perform any Ether transfer.

Error Handling: Ensure that you have enough balance in the contract to perform operations like recall. If the contract doesn't have enough Ether to cover the transfer in recall, the transaction will fail.

Check the Constructor: Make sure that the contract is deployed correctly with the right constructor parameters (if any).

Interaction in Remix: When interacting with the contract in Remix, ensure that you are using an account with enough Ether to cover the transaction costs, and that you're connected to the Sepolia test network.

Fallback and Receive Functions: If your contract is meant to receive Ether (since you have functions dealing with Ether transfers), you might need to implement a receive() or fallback() function to handle plain Ether transfers to the contract.

Testing: Test your contract thoroughly in Remix using the JavaScript VM before deploying it to the Sepolia testnet. This can help catch any logic errors.

If after checking these points you still face issues, the problem might be more specific to the environment or context in which you're executing the contract, such as the Remix setup, network issues, or account balances.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: I have adapted the function as follows, but unfortunately there is still an undefined gas volume. What could be the reason for this? 
    function transfer(address payable recipient, uint256 amount) external onlyAdmin {
        require(!confirmations[recipient], "Recipient already confirmed");
        require(amount <= transferLimit, "Exceeds transfer limit");

        // Markiere den Empfänger als bestätigt
        confirmations[recipient] = true;

        // Übertrage Ether an den Empfänger
        recipient.transfer(amount);

Comment: clearly a chatGPT answer